# Multi-Desktop-Platform complete GUI apps?

Tags: user-interface, installation, multiplatform

Is there a way to do a Multi-Desktop-Platform app?

(For Linux, Windows, and MacOS).

I want to do an setup application, to extract files, download files, execute OS command and format disks.

I want too do have a good-looking GUI, without a lot of lag (like Electron&Chromium), and compilable to one .exe/Linux Binary/MacOS app (so python will be complicated)

Which library/language do I need to use?